# How do I login if all login options are blocked in my company?

Tags: support, login

Many websites are blocked in the company I'm working at. Especially mail servers. For example, I can open aol.com at work, but I can't login to my mail, I can search using Google, but I can't login to gmail, etc. Same way, all available login options provided by stackoverflow are blocked at my work (though SO itself is accessible).
Why can't I just login with username and password?
What is the solution?

Comment: The Stack Exchange OpenId provider is blocked? Did you try to signup using the Stack Exchange option? And log in through it?

Comment: Stack Exchange login works! Thank you! I don't remember if I just missed this option or there was some temporary error at that time, but now I could log in.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why can't I just login with username and password?

You can. Click "log in using Stack Exchange" - you'll get a username/password option.

If *that* doesn't work, post the errors. Chances are, your employer is also blocking *something else* we need to make login work (possibly the scripts that run on that page) and you're out of luck... But depending on what, exactly, is being blocked we might be able to work around it.

Also make sure https://openid.stackexchange.com/ loads for you.

Comment: Stack Exchange login works! Thank you! I don't remember if I just missed this option or there was some temporary error at that time, but now I could log in.