# How to add email authenticated login with Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, login

When I created my Stack Overflow account I used 'register with Facebook' but at my workplace I don't have access to Facebook so I can't login with Facebook. I tried to add some other account but they all are login with Yahoo!, Gmail that also I can't open.

Is there any way to create a normal account for direct access without authenticating with email server?

**Edit**: It's not a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284040/how-do-i-login-if-all-login-options-are-blocked-in-my-company) because I don't have Stack Overflow ID and password.

Comment: how is it duplicate ? I said I don't have any specific username password for stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, probably I didn't picked the best question, though there are quite a few to choose from. Probably this one is more appropriate, as it gives all the exact steps to set up your Stack Exchange account : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers/114704#114704

Comment: Well, that question pointed to as a duplicate suggest you create a SO account. Why don't you create one, or a generic SE account?

Comment: if I create a new a generic SE account then how it will be linked to my existing  account ?